# Pandas transpose to new columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, transpose

I have the below dataframe that comes from a Microsoft forms, that I am downloading from a Sharepoint site using Python, and I need to save to our local database for further analysis.

Input DF:

```
ID  Q1  Q2  QN
1   1   1   0
2   1   1   1
3   0   0   1
4   0   1   0
```

Note that there are more than 50 columns, and rows some hundreds for now, but are going to increase during time.

Before sending the data to SQL Server I'd like to transpose the dataframe so that it is normalized for database storing. The output I'd like to get is the following:

Output DF:

```
ID  Question    Answer
1   Q1          1
1   Q2          1
1   QN          0
2   Q1          1
2   Q2          1
2   QN          1
3   Q1          0
3   Q2          0
3   QN          1
4   Q1          0
4   Q2          1
4   QN          0
```

I know that by simply transposing columns to rows using df.T I won't obtain much; can anyone please address some possible approach?
Even with plain Python lists/dictionaries or whatever, does not need to be necessarily handled with pandas.
Thanks

Comment: Please do not post images of the dataframes. You can simply do a print(df) and copy paste them in code blocks. That way its easier for others to use the data and solve your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `melt`:

```
df_new = df.set_index("ID").melt(var_name="Question", value_name="Answer", ignore_index=False).sort_index()
```

output:

```
   Question  Answer
ID
1        Q1       1
1        Q2       1
1        QN       0
2        Q1       1
2        Q2       1
2        QN       1
3        Q1       0
3        Q2       0
3        QN       1
4        Q1       0
4        Q2       1
4        QN       0
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different way to @anon01's answer would be to use the `id_var` parameter in `df.melt` instead of setting index explicitly ([documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)).

```
df.melt('ID', ['Q1','Q2','QN'], 'Question', 'Answer')
```

```
    ID Question  Answer
0    1       Q1       1
1    2       Q1       1
2    3       Q1       0
3    4       Q1       0
4    1       Q2       1
5    2       Q2       1
6    3       Q2       0
7    4       Q2       1
8    1       QN       0
9    2       QN       1
10   3       QN       1
11   4       QN       0
```

Comment: yes that would be a good solution too, thanks!

Comment: glad to help anytime.